# Printing out array data stored from File read

Tags: java, arrays, output, display

I'm trying to create a class that uses a separate method to read and store two sets of data from a file into 2 different arrays. I don't know if it's the read method or my output that is incorrect but I can't seem to figure out how to have it printout all data sets. I get the last line of the file instead of all content.

examples from products.txt are

Product1,1100

Product2,1205

Product3,1000

Main Method

```
    String[] pName;
    double[] pPrice;
    String outputStr = null;
    int i = 0;
    //String name = null; 
    
    // Input number of customers
            
    //initialize arrays with size
    pPrice=new double[50];
    pName=new String[50];
            
    // read from file, the method is incomplete
    try {
        readFromFile(pName, pPrice, "products.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File cannot be read");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < pName.length; i++) {  
    outputStr = pName[i] + "," + pPrice[i] + "\n";
    }
    // Call method before sorting both arrays
    display(outputStr);
```

Reading Method

```
    public static void readFromFile(String[] pName, double[] pPrice, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

     // read data from products
    // Create a File instance
    File file = new File(fileName);
                        
    // Create a Scanner for the file
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

     // Read data from a file, the data fields are separated by ',' 
    // Change the Scanner default delimiter to ','
    sc.useDelimiter(",|\r\n");
                        
      // Start reading data from file using while loop
    int i = 0;
     while (sc.hasNext()) {
                        
     String name = sc.next();
                           
     String cost = sc.next();
                                           
    //add the customer data through arrays
                                       
        pName[i] = name;
                               
        pPrice[i] = Double.parseDouble(cost);
                   
       i++;
         }//end while
      
    // Close the file
```

Comment: correct. I get the last line of the file instead of all content. examples from products.txt are Product1,1100
Product2,1205
Product3,1000
Product4,1230
Product5,3600
Product6,3200

Comment: That's because you call method `display` **after** the `for` loop has terminated. By the way, you should [edit] your question and add details rather than add them in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your for loop assigns every line to the outputStr variable:

```
for (i = 0; i < pName.length; i++) {  
    outputStr = pName[i] + "," + pPrice[i] + "\n";
}
```

Seeing your linefeed in the end I assume you want to concatenate all lines into that string variable. So change that code into

```
for (i = 0; i < pName.length; i++) {  
    outputStr += pName[i] + "," + pPrice[i] + "\n";
}
```

As you initialize the variable to be null this may throw a NullPointerException. If that is the case, simply initialize with "".